# How to update a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

*>Hello guys. I am making a program for my french lesson. My goal here is to make a word bank. My programs goal is to see if i added an 'i' word, or to add an 'i' word. I tried `wordBank.append()` but it didn't update the list. How can i update the word list? Code is below.*

```
wordBank = ["Apres", "Bureau", "Dejenuer", "Deime", "Dimanche", "jeudi", "Lundi", "Mardi", "Matin", "Midi",]

def hoşGeldin():
    inp1 = input("Fransızca kelime deposuna hoşgeldin!\nBaşlamak için 'Başla' yaz.\n")
    if inp1 == "Başla":
        istekNe()
    elif inp1 != "Başla":
        hoşGeldin()

def depoCheck():
    kelimeCheck = input("Bakmak istediğiniz kelimeyi yaz.\n")
    if kelimeCheck in wordBank:
        print("%s kelime listesinde" % kelimeCheck)

def istekNe():
    inp2 = input("Kelime aramak için Arat, Kelime eklemek için Yeni yaz.\n")
    if inp2 == "Arat":
        depoCheck()
    elif inp2 == "Yeni":
        yeniSözcük()
    elif inp2 != "Başla" or "Arat":
        istekNe()

def yeniSözcük():
    inp3 = input("Eklemek istediğiniz kelimeyi yaz.\n")
    wordBank.append("%s" % inp3)

inp1 = input("Fransızca kelime deposuna hoşgeldin!\nBaşlamak için 'Başla' yaz.\n")
if inp1 == "Başla":
    istekNe()
elif inp1 != "Başla":
    hoşGeldin()
```

Comment: Please don't provide external links to code. Provide a Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example instead: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
That helps hone in on the problem.

Comment: There is a difference between update and append. You need to clarify your post and edit with code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers!

Comment: Guys, i have got an idea. I was trying to make the whole program in just one folder but now i am going to delete `wordBank` and make .txt file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys i have now finished my project. I created a file named `fr.txt` and wrote all of the words and meanings of that words to there. For anyone who wonders my project i am leaving a paste.ee url here. [My French-Turkish dictonary](https://paste.ee/p/JbeoH)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code. I think it works well.
What happened is this:

> ```
> Fransızca kelime deposuna hoşgeldin!
> Başlamak için 'Başla' yaz.
> Başla
> Kelime aramak için Arat, Kelime eklemek için Yeni yaz.
> Yeni
> Eklemek istediğiniz kelimeyi yaz.
> New
> ```

After the above interaction, the items of ***wordBank*** are these:

['Apres',
 'Bureau',
 'Dejenuer',
 'Deime',
 'Dimanche',
 'jeudi',
 'Lundi',
 'Mardi',
 'Matin',
 'Midi',
 'New']

I think, because of the inputs that you provide, your program does not call ***yeniSözcük*** function in line 24, but if you provide proper inputs so your program call this function, your list will be updated.

Answer (score -1):

Python's **input()** is for reading numeric values. You need to change your code to **raw_input()** and try .

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow!  Since the OP tagged their question as "Python3", I'm not sure this will solve the issue.